# How to count correctly with more than one join?

Tags: mysql

I have to count 2 things in differents tables.

Tables:

```
[course]
id  |   name
1   |   Math
2   |   History
3   |   English

[class]
id  |   course_id
1   |   1
2   |   1
3   |   2
4   |   2
5   |   2
6   |   3
7   |   3
8   |   3

[lesson]
id  |   name            |   course_id
1   |   Basic           |   1
2   |   Intermediate    |   1
3   |   Advanced        |   3
```

When I user This queryto get ONE count and ONE join:

```
SELECT course.id, course.name, count(class.course_id) as totalCourses
FROM course
LEFT JOIN class ON class.course_id = course.id
GROUP BY course.id
```

I get the right result:

```
id      name        totalCourses
1   |   Math    |   2
2   |   History |   3
3   |   English |   3
```

But when i use the next query to get TWO counts and TWO joins the result is messed up

```
SELECT course.id, course.name, count(class.course_id) as totalCourses, count(lesson.course_id) as totalLessons
FROM course
LEFT JOIN class ON class.course_id = course.id
LEFT JOIN lesson ON lesson.course_id = course.id
GROUP BY course.id

id      name        totalCourses        totalLessons
1   |   Math    |   4               |       4
2   |   History |   3               |       0
3   |   English |   3               |       3
```

The result is wrong with the totalCourses AND with totalLessons

What is the right way to get TWO counts with TWO joins work?

Thanks!

Comment: With MySQL 8, you can do `SUM() OVER....`, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: run the query without count and you see because courseid 1 has 2 lessons the number doubles with thre ....

Comment: @nbk but if i remove count i just get the course_id.

Comment: remove both counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can first count the lessons number in a subselect and then join them

> ```
> CREATE TABLE course
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO course
>     (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Math'),
>     (2, 'History'),
>     (3, 'English')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE class
>     (`id` int, `course_id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO class
>     (`id`, `course_id`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 1),
>     (2, 1),
>     (3, 2),
>     (4, 2),
>     (5, 2),
>     (6, 3),
>     (7, 3),
>     (8, 3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE lesson
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(12), `course_id` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO lesson
>     (`id`, `name`, `course_id`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Basic', 1),
>     (2, 'Intermediate', 1),
>     (3, 'Advanced', 3)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(cl.course_id) , l.cont_1
> FROM course c
> LEFT JOIN class cl ON cl.course_id = c.id
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT course_id, COUNT(course_id) cont_1 FROM lesson GROUP BY course_id) l ON l.course_id = c.id
> GROUP BY c.id, c.name,l.cont_1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    | COUNT(cl.course_id) | cont_1
> -: | :------ | ------------------: | -----:
>  1 | Math    |                   2 |      2
>  2 | History |                   3 |   null
>  3 | English |                   3 |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=213f13ddc2169c6e07697127c8cd3b53)*

Comment: Almost!!. This is getting right totalLessons, but is messing with totalCourses: totalCourses should be 2,3,3 and not 2,1,1

Comment: i changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL 8, you can do `SUM() OVER....`, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

```
drop table if exists course;
drop table if exists class;
drop table if exists lesson;

create table course (id int, name varchar(20));
create table class (id int, course_id int);
create table lesson (id int, name varchar(20), course_id int);

insert into course values 
   (1,'Math'),
   (2,'History'),
   (3,'English');
insert into class values
   (1,1),   (2,1),
   (3,2),   (4,2),   (5,2),
   (6,3),   (7,3),   (8,3);
insert into lesson values
   (1,'Basic',1),
   (2,'Intermediate',1),
   (3,'Advanced', 3);
   
SELECT DISTINCT
   course.id, 
   course.name, 
   -- class.course_id as class,
   -- lesson.id as lesson,
   -- lesson.name,
   count(class.course_id) over (partition by course.id) as totalCourses, 
   count(lesson.id) over (partition by course.id,lesson.id) as totalLessons
FROM course
LEFT JOIN class ON class.course_id = course.id
LEFT JOIN lesson ON lesson.course_id = course.id
;
```

results:

```
+ ------- + --------- + ----------------- + ----------------- +
| id      | name      | totalCourses      | totalLessons      |
+ ------- + --------- + ----------------- + ----------------- +
| 1       | Math      | 4                 | 2                 |
| 2       | History   | 3                 | 0                 |
| 3       | English   | 3                 | 3                 |
+ ------- + --------- + ----------------- + ----------------- +
```

Comment: totalCourses and totalLessons are wrong. totalCourses should be 2,3,3 and totalLessons should be 2,0,1